# PWA and Window 10 API

Tags: windows, webpack, progressive-web-apps

How can I add "Open with" PWA app on Windows 10?

I know that Windows 10 has support to native API even in PWA, but I didn't found nothing related to my problem in the documentation.

Comment: Get to know the serviceWorker.

Comment: What's the point with service workers if I want to add a new item in the "Open with" menù on Windows?

Comment: are you trying to access the Windows APIs? If so you have to submit your PWA to the Windows Store.
If you just want to install the PWA from the browser then hook into the beforeinstallprompt event to trigger the prompt.

Comment: I have an already PWA compliant app, I'm searching for a way to add a new element inside "Open with" menù (that one that appears when you right click on a file in Windows) and open a file with my PWA app.